# python code for simple neural network to solve c = a1-a2 not working

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

I'm new to python and neural networks so I'd appreciate any assistance. trying to figure out how to make this simple NN that computes c = a1 - a2 but not sure where to start as there is no need for bias terms, if a=[(1,0),(0,0),(0,1)] then how can I compute c for each tuple? or find weights for the tensor?

```
training_data = np.array([[1,0],[0,0],[0,1]], "float32")
target_data = np.array([[1],[0],[-1]], "float32")

print("input : " + str(training_data))
print("output : " + str(target_data))

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.core.Dense(16, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.core.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs=100)
scores = model.evaluate(training_data, target_data)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
print (model.predict(training_data).round())
```

this is what I have but its accuracy (~33%) is very low and not sure what I am missing

Comment: With a training set the same size as your target set, that accuracy is not surprising.

Comment: Adding to @TimRoberts comment, I'd say that neural networks require significantly large datasets as input to achieve high accuracy as compared to traditional ML Models.

Comment: agreed, it's a very small training set. is there anything that anyone can suggest to improve the model? how can I include weight for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues here.

1. You are using a sigmoid output function, but your targets include negative numbers. Your model *cannot* work because sigmoid restricts the output to [0, 1]. In general, you have to think about your data range and what an appropriate output function can be. Here, just use *no* activation in the output layer.
2. Accuracy is meaningless for regression tasks as it will only count a match in case of an *exact* equality. Accuracy is only used for classification tasks. Thus, disregard accuracy completely and only look at the squared error/loss.
3. You are simply not training long enough. I increased to 1000 steps.
4. Note that your target function is linear, so you don't even need a hidden layer (but it doesn't hurt here, either).

With this code:

```
training_data = np.array([[1,0],[0,0],[0,1]], "float32")
target_data = np.array([[1],[0],[-1]], "float32")

print("input : " + str(training_data))
print("output : " + str(target_data))

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(training_data, target_data, epochs=1000)
scores = model.evaluate(training_data, target_data)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
print (model.predict(training_data))
```

I get outputs `[[ 1.0008523 ], [-0.00198349], [-0.99906766]]`.

NB the comments on your question are incorrect, you *should* expect a neural network to do very well on a small training set -- if it's not, something is likely wrong with your model and/or training process.